# Apache fails to restart after disabling SSL mod

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, apache-2.4

On Ubuntu trying to disable ssl in apache. But when I restart Apache, it fails...

a2dismod ssl

Result:

`Module ssl disabled. To activate the new configuration, you need to run: systemctl restart apache2`

systemctl restart apache2

Result:

`Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xeu apache2.service"`

apache2 log:

```
× apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2024-02-06 15:04:03 UTC; 13min ago
       Docs: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/
    Process: 26196 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 26ms

Feb 06 15:04:03 user systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Feb 06 15:04:03 user apachectl[26199]: AH00526: Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/ssl-params.conf:
Feb 06 15:04:03 user apachectl[26199]: Invalid command 'SSLCipherSuite', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
Feb 06 15:04:03 user apachectl[26196]: Action 'start' failed.
Feb 06 15:04:03 user apachectl[26196]: The Apache error log may have more information.
Feb 06 15:04:03 user systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Feb 06 15:04:03 user systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Feb 06 15:04:03 user systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
```

Comment: The error message that you posted says it all already *"AH00526: Syntax error on line 1 of `/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/ssl-params.conf`: Invalid command `SSLCipherSuite`, perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration"* --- That "module not included" is the modssl that you just disabled.

Comment: Hint: [`a2disconf`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/a2enconf.8.html)

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the problem is clearly shown in the error message:

> Feb 06 15:04:03 user apachectl[26199]: Invalid command 'SSLCipherSuite', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

So you disabled the SSL module but still used configuration options only available with this module. You need to remove these configuration options too.